Dynamic Output Naming in QGIS Based on Input
How can I set the output name dynamically based on the input that is provided?
I would like the output name to always be the "@input name" + the suffix "_new".


I have the model:

It buffers an input line layer, and loads the output layer into the project.
Load layer into project have Loaded layer name set to the Pre-calculated value:
concat(layer_property( layer:= @vector_layer , property:='name'), '_buffered')
layer_property reads the input layers name and concatenates it with _buffered to give it that suffix:

